# How to filter nginx spam one url

Tags: nginx, networking, firewall

i have problem with simple flood attacks and don't know how to prevent this.
In logs there is huge load of requests from various IP and my application stuck and server going 100% cpu and memory

```
103.124.xxx.xx - - [14/Jul/2022:18:41:48 +0200] "GET /playlist/qXsaq2m7fj/ha3jRVCPTY/m3u_plus?output=hls HTTP/1.1" 502 552 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
45.160.xxx.xxx - - [14/Jul/2022:18:41:48 +0200] "GET /playlist/qXsaq2m7fj/ha3jRVCPTY/m3u_plus?output=hls HTTP/1.1" 502 552 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.864.71"
79.143.xxx.xxx - - [14/Jul/2022:18:41:48 +0200] "GET /playlist/qXsaq2m7fj/ha3jRVCPTY/m3u_plus?output=hls HTTP/1.1" 502 552 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36"
75.110.xxx.xx - - [14/Jul/2022:18:41:48 +0200] "GET /playlist/qXsaq2m7fj/ha3jRVCPTY/m3u_plus?output=hls HTTP/1.1" 502 552 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36"
```

I tried with **limit_req_zone** but no result, maybe someone have better idea.

//edit:
Most of addresses do only one or two requests so i can't catch this.

Comment: Are the URLs valid ones for your website?

Comment: Yes, urls are valid.

Comment: I think nothing much to do aside from checking if those IPs belong to specific networks and blocking entire networks. Run a `whois` on those IPs and see if it comes from e.g. a hosting company that is not supposed to have any genuine traffic to your website.

Comment: Is there possibility to create script which block IP when there is much POST or GET requests on one URL from various IPs? UFW or iptables?

Comment: How you will know if you're not blocking a genuine visitor? Maybe [this module](https://docs.addesp.com/ngx_waf/practice/protect-against-distributed-http-flood.html) can help you.